# Difference between char[] and &char[]?

Tags: c

I'm trying to better understand the & operator (address-of) for use within an API.

Here is my example API function signature:

```
apiFunction(const int*)
```

I am working on somebody else's code and they are using the API as follows:

```
int inputs[1] = {1};
apiFunction((const int*)&inputs);
```

I would think the correct usage should be:

```
int inputs[1] = {1};
apiFunction(inputs);
```

Is there a difference between 'inputs' and '&inputs' when 'inputs' is a char array with length 1?

They looks the same when I do a printf, but I fear that I may be formatting it incorrectly:

```
printf("%p, %p", inputs, (const int*)&inputs);
```

Output (for example):

```
0204DE94 0204DE94
```

Comment: Why do you need to cast `&inputs`? That should be the type you're looking for automatically. It's also the responsibility of the caller to correctly encode the arguments, so calling `&` when an address is required shouldn't come as a surprise.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying

Comment: @tadman maybe he is compiling using C++ compiler.

Comment: Waht is the reason of declaring table with the length 1?

Comment: @PeterJ Purpose for length 1 array is not obvious because I have simplified the actual code I'm working on. API actually accepts array length and then a pointer to the array of inputs. API can handle more than 1 input, but for my application I only need 1 input.

Comment: @tadman Agreed. The surprise is that &inputs is the "address of the array" and not the "address of the address of the array".

Comment: Why would `&inputs` be the address of the address? `&` loosely translates to "address of" in C.

Comment: @tadman because inputs without the & operator is an int* (and a pointer is an address) obviously I'm wrong, but trying to explain my thought process

Comment: Don't confuse "can be interpreted as" with "is actually". C treats arrays and pointers as two sides of the same coin, but they're not literally the same thing. The compiler will handle the conversion for you if necessary, but some conversion is necessarily required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `&input` has type `int (*)[1]`, i.e. a *pointer to an array* of size 1.  This is in contrast to `input` which (in most contexts) decays to a pointer to the first element and has type `int *`.

While the address of an array and the address of the first element are the same, the difference in the type of each one comes into play when pointer arithmetic is applied.

In the context of `apiFunction` which expects a `const int *`, you can get away with passing either `&input` (with a cast) or `input` as both have the same value.  However, the latter is the proper way to do this:

```
apiFunction(inputs);
```

So you are correct that the code you found is not passing the parameter properly.

Comment: Code is not passing parameter properly, but it is functionally OK because they have the same value. That's what I'm getting from your answer

Comment: Usually when something with pointers is functionally OK because they have the same value, it’s technically UB but the compiler does the obvious thing and it works out in practice. In this case I think it actually is well-defined as doing the same thing.

Comment: @Caprooja That is correct, it works because `input` and `&input` have the same value.

Comment: @DanielH It is the cast `(const int*)&inputs` that is weak.  Converting from a `int**` to `const int*`.  IIRC, the pointer to a simple type like `int` may be of different size _and representation_ (and if properly converted _equate_ to each other)  than a `pointer to a pointer` and the conversion is a problem, unless it goes through `void *`.  OTOH, [the speed limit is 55](https://www.reddit.com/r/NoStupidQuestions/comments/2xy8ra/why_does_noone_in_the_us_follow_the_speed_limit/)

Comment: There are no pointers to pointers; decay doesn’t happen there. `&inputs` has type `int[1]*`, or pointer to array of one `int`. I think you can convert between a pointer to an array and a pointer to its element type, at least if its elements are standard layout and probably no matter what.

Comment: (Oops, I wrote the type wrong; it’s really `int  (*)[1]`)